# Sass Loader Error: Invalid options object that does not match the API schema

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, sass, node-modules

I'm using VueJS with the framework [VuetifyJS](https://vuetifyjs.com) (v2.0.19). I'm getting this error after running *npm run serve*:

> Sass Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not
>   match the API schema.

What I tried:
I've deleted the *node_modules* folder and reinstalled/updated all npm packages and node.js to the latest stable version.

Full error message:

```
 error  in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VRangeSlider/VRangeSlider.sass

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'indentedSyntax'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (/home/do/Desktop/A/Projects/Ral/AppCLI3/node_modules/sass-loader/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:50:11)
    at Object.loader (/home/do/Desktop/A/Projects/Ral/AppCLI3/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:36:28)

 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VRangeSlider/VRangeSlider.sass 4:14-208 14:3-18:5 15:22-216
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VRangeSlider/VRangeSlider.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VRangeSlider/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.2.115:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/main.sass
```

My package.json:

```
  {
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.2.1",
    "fibers": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase": "^7.0.0",
    "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-flickity": "^1.2.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.0.19",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^4.4.95",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.3",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^5.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.7",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.6.3",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-console": "off"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 120):

Seems same issue like here:
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2206

Solution is

```
npm uninstall --save-dev sass-loader
npm install --save-dev sass-loader@7.1.0
```

Comment: Downgrading never seemed to me like the most elegant approach, yet it's the only thing that did the trick for me. The answer below by https://stackoverflow.com/users/5302733/diego-alberto-zapata-h%c3%a4ntsch , however complete, left me with the same error.

Comment: Worked for me May 2020

Comment: Worked for me in May 2020. Looks like people are still talking about it: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4513

Comment: using vue-cli 3 and vue 2.6, sass-loader v8.0.0 worked for me...I did `yarn remove sass-loader && yarn add -D sass-loader@8.0.0`

Comment: This is the quickest (and easiest) fix path on Nuxt

Comment: 8.0.0 didn't work for me (same error) but 7.1.0 did. Nuxt 2.14.

Comment: This worked for me in june 2021 though the installation asked me to upgrade too but I suggest people should refer to other newer answers here!..

Answer (score 49):

**Problem**

Based on [vue-cli - github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4513), If you did upgrade your `sass-loader` from `v7` to `8` or `9`, You may have faced with the **validation-error** for invalid options :

> vue.config.js(valid syntax for sass-loaderv7 in webpack)

```
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "@/assets/styles/variables/index.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
```

> errors

```
object:
    ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been
    initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
      - options has an unknown property 'data'. These properties are valid:
```

**sass-loader v8.0 Breaking Changes**

You should know that v8. has below [breaking changes](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v8.0.0)

- minimum required webpack version is 4.36.0
- minimum required node.js version is 8.9.0
- move all sass (includePaths, importer, functions) options to the
  sassOptions option. The functions option can't be used as Function,
  you should use sassOption as Function to achieve this.
- the data option was renamed to the prependData option default value
  of the sourceMap option depends on the devtool value (eval/false
  values don't enable source map generation)

**Solution v8**

As the docs says:

- move all sass (`includePaths`, `importer`, `functions`) options to the `sassOptions` option. The `functions` option can't be used as Function, you should use `sassOption` as Function to achieve this.
- the `data` option was renamed to the `prependData` option

**sass-loader v9.0 Breaking Changes**

You should know that v9. has below [breaking changes](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v9.0.0)

- BREAKING CHANGES minimum supported Nodejs version is 10.13
- prefer sass (dart-sass) by default, it is strongly recommended to
  migrate on sass (dart-sass)
- the prependData option was removed in favor the    additionalData
  option, see docs
- when the sourceMap is true,    sassOptions.sourceMap,
  sassOptions.sourceMapContents,    sassOptions.sourceMapEmbed,
  sassOptions.sourceMapRoot and    sassOptions.omitSourceMapUrl will be
  ignored.

**Solution v9**

In ver9 as you can see in the [options](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#options), [sassOption](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#sassoptions) , [additionalData](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#additionaldata), if we change `data` to `additionalData` it will fix the invalid options errors.

```
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `@import "@/assets/styles/variables/index.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 28):

If you are using `vue-cli 4` and in order to avoid this error you need to change the config of `sass-loader` in `vue.config.js` like the example below, after that the error will be fixed.

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack(config) {
    config
      .entry('app')
      .clear()
      .add('./src/core/main.js')
      .end();
    config.resolve.alias
      .set('~', path.join(__dirname, './src'))
      .set('@', path.join(__dirname, './src/core'))
      .set('#', path.join(__dirname, './src/modules'))
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        sassOptions: {
          includePaths: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/core/')
          ],
          indentedSyntax: true,
        },
        prependData: '@import "~@/assets/sass/main.scss"',
      },
    },
  },
  assetsDir: '@/assets/',
}
```

Don't forget to specify your own configuration.
Please checkout the configuration on the [sass-loader repo](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader).

If you use `vue cli 3`, it works with `sass-loader v7` not with `v8` if you use `vue cli 3` and `sass-loader v7` the previous configuration still works.

Good luck and regards.

**UPDATE (2021):**

As [@gdaniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6412052/gdaniel) said in the comment, the sass-loader team changed from `prependData` to `additionalData` property in the options, as you can see in the following [commit **062991588769f2**](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/commit/062991588769f20bd9887a2913e8fdd22ac7eedb).

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: The changes are `data` -> `prependData` and `includePaths` to `sassOptions.includePaths` (inside new object). All of this happens within the object with the key of `sass`.

Comment: It solved my problem.  The documentation is not very user friendly, but you gave it a better direction.

Comment: they've gone from using data to prependData to additionalData

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue when upgrading to sass-loader 10. I resolved it by replacing `prependData` with **`additionalData`** as per below:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: 'sass-loader',
  options: {
    additionalData: `@import 'src/scss/helpers/variables';`
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah, the new API implements the `additionalData` option 

Comment: where to put this?

Answer (score 6):

`indentedSyntax` is part of the `sassOptions`:

```
sassOptions: {  indentedSyntax: true  }
```

For example:

```
{
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    options: {
        sassOptions: {
            indentedSyntax: true
        }
    }
}
```

So - change your Webpack config to reflect that.

Comment: I can't get it to run and received an error within the CLI to use *new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({* because *load options* is outdated. I'm using _vue.config.js_ (Vue CLI 3) to configure webpack. Can you please post some more details.

Comment: How did you create the app (vue init with template, vue create), also: Post that vue.config.js

Answer (score 3):

if you are using an updated version of sass-loader you need to use additional data instead of data

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
      loaderOptions: {
        sass: {
            additionalData: `@import "@/styles/base.scss";`
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to downgrage sass-loader, after which I got the real error emmitted on the terminal when I run `ng serve`, which whould be `vue-cli-service` in your case
I think it's a problem with v8 of sass-loader, will dig further

In the meantime, this might help: In the package.json, edit the sass-loader to read `"sass-loader": "7.0.1",`

Answer (score 1):

change `data` to `prependData`. Final result (vue.config.js):

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                prependData: `@import "@/sass/variables.sass"`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those still struggling and still do not have a solution for this with sass-loader v8:

```js
const includePaths = [
  'mypath'
]

module.exports = {
  // ... other config here

  css: {
    extract: false,
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        sassOptions: { // <<<< This wrapper is needed!
          // ... all options here, e.g. prependData, includePaths a.s.o.
          includePaths  
        }
      }
    }
  },

  // ... other config here
}
```

Comment: HI..thanks for the solution. What should actually be in the `sassOptions` object ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [current docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders) and assuming sass-loader 8+ this is the syntax for importing globally. This imports a file from `src/styles/..whatever`

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: `@import "~@/styles/[rest of path to import]";`,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Vue 3 with Vue CLI 4.5 that used Webpack 4 and was facing the same issue.

This worked for me:

Upgrade to sass-loader 10:

```
npm uninstall -D sass-loader
npm install -D sass-loader@^10
```

Vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "~@/scss/colors.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://www.catagec.com/blog/load-a-global-scss-file-in-vue-3/