# How to upgrade sass-loader

Tags: vue.js, sass

I use vue and when I run it, there is a warning. I tried `npm update` without luck. How to get rid off it?

```
vue-cli-service serve
WARN  A new version of sass-loader is available. Please upgrade for best experience.
```

Comment: Have you tried `npm i sass-loader@latest`

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Why update did not help? There was "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"

Comment: In most cases we specify the version in the `package.json` like this `^7.1.0` and that says that we allow to update ony the **minor** versions. So `npm update` will not touch the **major** version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Serg** already gave the answer in comment. It's worked for me. Adding the answer for others. Hope it will help others.

Just run this command

```
npm i sass-loader@latest
```

Answer (score 4):

You can update your packages via using `yarn upgrade-interactive --latest`, in case of sass-loader, if you have upgrade it from 7 to 9, you may have some `invalid options erros` which you can fixed in below  steps as I've explained before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62844942/12666332

**Problem**

Based on https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4513, And If you have upgrade your sass-loader from v7 to 8 or 9, You may have faced with th validation-error for invalid options

> vue.config.js(valid syntax for sass-loaderv7 in webpack)

```
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "@/assets/styles/variables/index.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
```

> errors

```
object:
    ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been
    initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
      - options has an unknown property 'data'. These properties are valid:
```

**sass-loader v8.0 Breaking Changes**

You should know that v8. has below breaking changes :https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v8.0.0

- minimum required webpack version is 4.36.0
- minimum required node.js version is 8.9.0
- move all sass (includePaths, importer, functions) options to the
  sassOptions option. The functions option can't be used as Function,
  you should use sassOption as Function to achieve this.
- the data option was renamed to the prependData option default value
  of the sourceMap option depends on the devtool value (eval/false
  values don't enable source map generation)

**Solution v8**

As the docs says, `move all sass (includePaths, importer, functions) options to the sassOptions option. The functions option can't be used as Function, you should use sassOption as Function to achieve this.`
`the data option was renamed to the prependData option`

**sass-loader v9.0 Breaking Changes**

You should know that v9. has below breaking changes :https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v9.0.0

- BREAKING CHANGES minimum supported Nodejs version is 10.13
- prefer sass (dart-sass) by default, it is strongly recommended to
  migrate on sass (dart-sass)
- the prependData option was removed in favor the    additionalData
  option, see docs
- when the sourceMap is true,    sassOptions.sourceMap,
  sassOptions.sourceMapContents,    sassOptions.sourceMapEmbed,
  sassOptions.sourceMapRoot and    sassOptions.omitSourceMapUrl will be
  ignored.

**Solution v9**

In ver9 as you can see in the docs https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#options (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#sassoptions , https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#additionaldata), if we change `data` to `additionalData` if will fix the invalid options errors.

```
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `@import "@/assets/styles/variables/index.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
```