# Configure Vue.js 2 project to use SCSS

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am trying to add scss to my Vue.js 2 project, but for some reason it is not working. I tried installing the following:

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass style-loader --save-dev
```

Inside my build folder, I have webpack files, and there inside `webpack.base.conf.js` I tried to add loader:

```
loaders: [
      ...
// this one
      {
          test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
          loader: 'style!css!sass'
      }
    ]
```

Inside the build folder, there is also `vue-loader.conf.js` file, with this piece of code:

```
loaders: utils.cssLoaders({
    sourceMap: sourceMapEnabled,
    extract: isProduction
  }),
```

Should I change that to something else? I am new to vue, and what I found so far is not doing the job. I tried putting `lang="scss"` in `style` tag, but it throws an error after it.

This is how my build folder looks like, with the webpack files:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your console error log?

Comment: @s4k1b This is the error:

Module build failed: ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184549/sass-loader-error-invalid-options-object-that-does-not-match-the-api-schema

may be checkout this

Comment: @s4k1b yeah, checked it out already but downgrading won't do the trick for me :/

Comment: I personally use `sass-loader@7.1.0` and `node-sass@4.11.0`
I don't need to write any config files, and it works

Comment: Also, checkout the issue here, https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4513