# How to fix 'Typescript "Type checking in progress..." taking too long'?

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, cpu-usage, typechecking

Every time i run the project and change something in a file in my `Vuejs front-end app` which is using typescript, the typescript/webpack instantly tells compiled successfully like: `DONE  Compiled successfully in 635ms` but the type checking will takes too long to tell there is error or not like: `No type errors found Version: typescript 3.9.6 Time: 41131ms` and it will use `high cpu usage` for this type checking  which i think it is harm full for my laptop in a 8h/day developing.

[image]

I tried to set some flags in `tsconfig.json` as the docs says https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html:

```
    "incremental": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./buildcache/front-end",
```

But nothing has been changed , I also tried `"watch":true` , but it didn't for either. So I wonder how should we fix this problem with typescript type checking's problems( taking too long to check and high cpu usage)

**Update**

Here is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**Update2**

You can use this https://github.com/SeyyedKhandon/vuejs-persian-chat-scaffold as a reprex (clone `typecheck` branch), and as you can see in this simple app, it takes 2 seconds to type-check, which is not acceptable at all. Does it related to `vue-composition-api plugin`?

**Update3**

I found-out there is a flag named `"skipLibCheck": true` in `tsconfig.json` , which skips lib type checks which made type-checking `2x faster`. but still its not good enough.

Comment: You could try excluding node modules from the type checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spent lots of time on this problem, I decided to upgrade `package.json`, at the first step I've upgrade 3 packages  including `"@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.0-beta.3" -> "^1.0.0-beta.10"` and   `"sass-loader": "^7.1.0" -> "^9.0.3"` and   `"typescript": "~3.9.3", -> "~3.9.7"`, and suddenly the typechecking time decreases to `4s`, which was very good promising.

So, here is what i did :

1.use `"skipLibCheck": true` flag in `tsconfig.json` , which skips lib type checks which will make type-checking 2x faster.

2. if the problem still exists `->` upgrade your `package.json`

you can use `yarn upgrade-interactive --latest` but be careful about breaking changes(read the docs to fix you problems, in case of sass-loader upgrading if you have issue read https://stackoverflow.com/a/62844942/12666332)