# Laravel mix.sass "prependData" not supplying data to scss files

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-mix

I have a mix file, and I'm passing it the data like this:

```
mix.sass('resources/sass/styles.scss', 'public/assets/css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        prependData: '$test: testing prepend;',
        postCss: [tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js')],
    });
```

And I'm just doing this:

```
body {
    content: $test;
}
```

To test if I get the $test variable.
However, when I run the app, I get:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

P.S:
php artisan --version returns: 8.48.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prependData` not inside `options` but as a third parameter of a `sass` method like it said [here](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/sass#plugin-options)

> Behind the scenes, Laravel Mix of course defers to webpack's sass-loader to load and compile your Sass files. From time to time, you may need to override the default options that we pass to it. Use the third argument to mix.sass() in these scenarios.

```
mix.sass('src/app.scss', 'dist', {
    sassOptions: {
        outputStyle: 'nested'
    }
});
```

So in your case it woould be

```
mix.sass('resources/sass/styles.scss', 'public/assets/css', {
        additionalData: '$test: testing prepend;',
    })
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js')],
    });
```

Comment: I tried that before as well I think, and when I do that, I get this error:

`ERROR in ./resources/sass/styles.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.`

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184549/sass-loader-error-invalid-options-object-that-does-not-match-the-api-schema answer your question?

Comment: I figured it out, its `additionalData` now, instead of `prependData`